# Send a Complex Object as a Parameter to Post Action in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to send a parameter with `submit` button to post action so there is my sample:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Search", controllerName: "MyController", routeValues: new { rv = "102" })) {

   ...
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

And this is My Search Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Search(string rv, FormCollection collection) {

 ...
}
```

So Every thing is fine until now,

Then I try to Send a complex object like a `Dictionary<string, string>`

So you can just replace `string` type of `rv` parameter with `Dictionary<string, string>` and send a dictionary, but in this case the `rv` value always returned a dictionary with 0 count? where is the problem? How can I send a dictionary to post action?

**Update**

I Also try this one but not worked yet (Mean rv steel is a dictionary with 0 count):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Search", controllerName: "MyController", routeValues: new { rv = Model.MyDictionary }, method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "FilterForm" })) {

 ...
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Search(Dictionary<string, string> rv, FormCollection collection) {

 ...
}
```

Comment: you mean this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038386/begin-form-with-overload-that-accepts-routevalues-and-htmlattributes OR this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028288/mvc3-html-beginform-passing-arguments-as-routevaluedictionary-fails

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi The links you mentioned not worked for me, I update the question

Comment: what are you trying to send in the dictionary ? How does your view looks like ? Are you trying to do Model Binding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send complex objects. Please read the [following article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) to the understand the expected wire format that the default model binder expects if you want to be able to deserialize the object to a collection or a dictionary.

So after reading ScottHa's article and understanding the expected wire format for dictionaries you could roll a custom extension method that will convert your dictionary to a RouteValueDictionary following the conventions:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        var values = new RouteValueDictionary();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            values[string.Format("[{0}].Key", i)] = item.Key;
            values[string.Format("[{0}].Value", i)] = item.Value;
            i++;
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

and then in your view you could use this extension method:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(
    actionName: "Search", 
    controllerName: "MyController", 
    routeValues: Model.MyDictionary.ToRouteValues(), 
    method: FormMethod.Post, 
    htmlAttributes: new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "FilterForm" }))
) 
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously here I assume that `Model.MyDictionary` is an `IDictionary<string, string>` property.