# BeginForm overload that accepts RouteValueDictionary and Dictionary<string,object> as htmlParameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.beginform

I came across [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038386/begin-form-with-overload-that-accepts-routevalues-and-htmlattributes) from 2009 that is asking the exact same question as I am now, but the solution no longer appears to work.  I am currently using MVC 5.

I am calling `BeginForm` like this:

```
helper.BeginForm("Edit", controllerName, new { id }, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes.Attributes);
```

`htmlAttributes.Attributes` is `Dictionary<string, object>`.  The form ends up generating this markup:

```
<form 
    comparer="System.OrdinalComparer" 
    count="2" 
    keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" 
    values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" 
    action="/CustomerDocumentTypeAdmin/Edit/1" 
    method="post">
```

You can clearly see that it's reflecting over the dictionary class itself and using its properties as the HTML attributes.

Previously, I was declaring my attributes like this:

```
new { id = "formId" }
```

I changed it to a dictionary because I need to be able to modify the value collection at any stage in the call stack.

The `HtmlHelper` extension overload that my call resolves to is this:

```
MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);
```

The signature of my call certainly matches it, and the question I linked to seems to as well.  Not sure why it's not working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an overload that I can use which means I need to change the type of one of my parameters.  This is the overload:

```
MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

This means I need to pass `new { id }` into a `RouteValueDictionary` like so:

```
helper.BeginForm("Edit", controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(new { id }), FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes.Attributes)
```

I could also pass a dictionary into the `RouteValueDictionary`, but not sure how marginal the performance difference would be.  At any rate, this now works.